# How to Remove Intel Anti-Theft?

Tags: windows-8, anti-theft

I just upgraded to Windows 8 and guess what? You need a different version of the program on Windows 8. Now, how do I remove it? I can't deactivate it in BIOS. Do I have to re-install Windows 7 again to uninstall this program?

It is a laptop yes, X230 Tablet. How do I remove it?

Comment: What kinds of problems is this causing?

Comment: The laptop will lock down after 21 days... :p Because it cant't talk to intel.

Comment: This question does not provide any helpful information for us to answer it correctly. I'm voting to close.

Comment: "Close this and I'll just get up another one." The preferred method is to edit the question to resolve the problem and your question will be reopened.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be able to remove it. Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: @data_jepp why so hostile?  People are doing their best to try and help

Comment: @ernie Sorry, I spent 30 minutes on the phone with tech support. I have to get an upgraded service, they want me to pay for a slighty different version of the software so it will work on windows 8. I'm really angy at that.

Comment: This is the new software model for all companies, pay, pay, pay for the rest of your life. Software and the internet is being monetized like a rental car, like it or not, it sucks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell lenovo [provides the software for windows 8](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=DS032435). Just use the software provided for windows 8, and if you still want to remove it, you should be able to disable it from inside the software without re-installing windows 7. After that you can just uninstall the management software if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article from Intel on just your situation. Hope this helps
http://www.intel.com/support/services/anti-theft-svc/sb/CS-033857.htm

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Is this a laptop? You should provide more information about your hardware as there are [model-specific](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=SF10-D0098) ways to disable Intel AMT(which in turn disables Intel vPro/"anti-theft").

Comment: Of course its a laptop, the author, even said ( by a comment ) well before your answer it was one.